# Magento 1: Ajax URL returns 404 in a custom module when moved site to another server

Tags: ajax, custom-controls, magento-1.9

I'M bit new to Magento development.
I just moved website to another server and the ajax call start return 404.
Could you please help me how to debug or resolve this issue ?

**Orignal site (working fine)**

Click on any product here in shop now section
Website URL: `https://mastermindcrate.com/`

Ajax URL is : `https://mastermindcrate.com/waytwoexpert/index/getProductDetail`

**Moved Site (Error exist here)**
I moved site to : `http://yasirjamal.com/demo/mastermind-new/`

Ajax URL is: `http://yasirjamal.com/demo/mastermind-new/waytwoexpert/index/getProductDetail`
When i click on any product shop now section here it returns 404 see screenshot here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `index.php` from secure frontend url otherwise you have to use index.php in your url to access specific route

For eg.

```
http://yasirjamal.com/demo/mastermind-new/index.php/waytwoexpert/index/getProductDetail
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.. could you please tell me this part of url waytwoexpert/index/getProductDetail   point to which file? i want to know where actually ajax call is going to get the data. i hope you get my point.. thanks